# How to achieve this grain texture - Photoshop or illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, illustration, texture

Ok, new to textures here and I really cant figure out how this grain effect/texture was achieved -

[image]

It is very subtle and basic google searches thru PS geometric textures haven't yielded anything. The basic grain effects in Illustrator/PS are also not like this.

How was this done? Is this an overlay?

Comment: It's a fabric pattern of some sorts.

Comment: Some places it looks like plain old checkered dithering, other places it looks almost like a tiny raster dot pattern. It's hard to tell though because the jpeg compression blurs the texture - especially in the bottom of the image. Looks a little messy. Do you have a non-compressed png of the image where the texture is intact?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some kind of dither pattern, but it's hard to tell for sure since there are some jpeg compression artefacts.

Here's one method to add a simple dither pattern/texture to an image.

1. Open an image in Photoshop
2. Select All (CTRL+A). Copy (CTRL+C). Use Command instead of CTRL on Mac.
3. File > New, make sure it's an RGB image, and choose the "clipboard" option for the size.
4. Edit > Fill, choose 50% gray.
5. Image > Mode > Indexed
6. Set the options as shown below, and hit OK. You can see an example of the dither pattern behind the dialog box.

[image]

7. Select all (CTRL+A), Copy (CTRL+C)
8. Go back to your image
9. Paste (CTRL+V)
10. Set the layer mode in the layers panel to "Soft Light" or experiment with other blending modes.

Example showing before and after. Click on the image to see the texture at full size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

User Billy Kerr suggested modifying the brightness with a dense regular dot pattern. That's not bad except it doesn't explain the variety which is in questioner's example.

The variety can be explained with interaction of two different dot patterns. It's the same as Moire patterns when one tries to scan a printed image. Actually there's also a third pattern, the screen pixels, but it can be eliminated with high enough zoom.

In the next image there's a quite flat BW photo taken from window's image samples. On top of the image is 4x4 pixel BW checkerboard pattern with low opacity and blending mode Multiply. The result is quite same as in Billy Kerr's answer.

[image]

The pattern variations in questioner's image seem to follow coarsely contrast borders in his image. I guess the reqular pattern has got a displacement map, which is some version of the image. Maybe a contrast boosted, a little blurred and desaturated version of the image is saved and used as the map in Filter > Distort > Displace. When layered, tn original dot pattern somewhere neutralizes the displaced pattern and somewhere gains it. Here's an example:

[image]

The displaced pattern itself has variations for the same reason, the dots are here and there pleated. Having the original pattern, too makes possible to try different mixes with the opacity sliders.

Here's another result with different settings in displament scaling and the opacities:

[image]